# XNA DrawPrimitives unintended line to 0,0

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to learn XNA.
I'm currently drawing a figure on the screen where the user clicks.
I use an indexbuffer and PrimitiveType.LineList.
It works fine, however occasionally a line is drawn between a figure's first vertex and what seems like position 0,0. Why is it doing that?

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Draw Code**

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.CornflowerBlue);

        #region Transform //Covered later in the Course
        effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
        effect.View = new Matrix(
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        );
        effect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
              0f, this.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width,
              this.GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height, 0f,
            -10f, 10f
        );
        #endregion -> Wordt later behandeld
        if (vertex.Count > 0)
        {
            VertexBuffer vBuffer = new VertexBuffer(this.GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), vertex.Count, BufferUsage.None);
            vBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionColor>(vertex.ToArray());

            this.GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vBuffer);


            effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

            this.GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 0, 0, this.vertex.Count, 0, vertex.Count * 2);
        }

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

**Add Figure Code**

```
    private void addFigure(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point location, Size size, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color color)
    {
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X, location.Y - 40, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 10, location.Y - 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 20, location.Y - 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 20, location.Y - 10, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 40, location.Y, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 20, location.Y + 10, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 20, location.Y + 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X + 10, location.Y + 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X, location.Y + 40, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 10, location.Y + 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 20, location.Y + 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 20, location.Y + 10, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 40, location.Y, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 20, location.Y - 10, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 20, location.Y - 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));
        this.vertex.Add(new VertexPositionColor(new Vector3(location.X - 10, location.Y - 20, 0), Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Red));

        for (short i = 16; i > 0; i--)
        {
            this.index.Add((short)(this.vertex.Count - i));
            if (i - 1 > 0)
            {
                this.index.Add((short)(this.vertex.Count - i + 1));
            }
            else
            {
                this.index.Add((short)(this.vertex.Count - 16));
            }
        }

        this.ib = new IndexBuffer(this.GraphicsDevice, typeof(short), this.index.Count, BufferUsage.None);
        this.ib.SetData<short>(this.index.ToArray());
        this.GraphicsDevice.Indices = ib;
    }
```

Comment: Still XNA ? It's discontinued already.

Comment: I had to learn this at school, they changed it the year after I followed it :\

Answer (score 0):

This is the problematic line:

```
this.GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 
    0, 0, this.vertex.Count, 0, vertex.Count * 2);
```

You specify that you have twice as many lines as vertices. But you only have equally many. There is probably some uninitialized garbage after the buffer, which is interpreted as the origin.

It should be:

```
this.GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.LineList, 
    0, 0, this.vertex.Count, 0, vertex.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`PrimitiveBatch` sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives) at the MSDN. It's a bit old but will give you a general idea on how to handle primitives. I myself have been using this for the game I'm currently developing and I like the way it turned out.

You can use this to draw lines and make more complicated shapes with them. Should also be cleaner code-wise.